# ubuntu bootloader doesn't detect window 8

Tags: grub2, windows-8, bootloader

After installing ubuntu, using something else option and installing it on a different disk than windows 8 , I starting my computer and ubuntu loaded without any boot loader. So I searched in internet and the only fix I understand was with the boot repair application. I downloaded it, installed it and started recommended repair, which worked fine and created a grub loader,but it was without option for windows 8. And now even if I set from BIOS to boot the disk with the windows 8 first, it will start grub. It would be great if someone can tell how to solve it step by step.

This is the summary info from boot repair - http://paste.ubuntu.com/9480014/

Comment: You are missing the Windows boot partition, usually 100MB and just before the main install and hidden in Windows. It does look like you have boot flag on sda2 and bootmgr, so all you should need is a BCD. You cannot create nor repair a BCD from Linux, but need your Windows repair CD or flash drive or some third party Windows repair tools will create or fix a BCD. I would also reconfigure your installs so Windows is totally on one drive and Ubuntu totally on the other drive.

Comment: did Summoned Egar's answer worked ?

Comment: @oldfred It looks to me like the bootflag on `sda2` is what Windows usually does to mark a partition as "active" in Windows terms (simply speaking, I wouldn't be concerned about that). The behavior of boot-repair in this case is somehow *interesting*, looks like someone decided that Windows' System Partition (what could act as an ESP) is "completely useless" and programmed boot-repair to format it with EXT4 to embed GRUB. Also I assume that GRUB doesn't rely on boot flags, but cannot parse extended partitions, so that GRUB on `sdb` couldn't find the UUID. At least, that would make sense to me.

Comment: Boot-Repair does not create or format partitions, you have to do that outside of Boot-Repair. The installer may have done that if the user specified it. Boot-Repair does copy the bootmgr from the 100MB Windows boot partition in BIOS to the main partition as so many users delete the 100MB partition not knowing what it is. Grub does not use boot flag, but can easily parse extended partitions. Boot-Repair may have moved the  boot flag as it sometimes does that and not always correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try using super-grub

http://www.supergrubdisk.org/

Just install it on a usb and boot it (you can use YUMI or Universal Usb Installer), it will automatically find the O.S. installed.

Once it boots do:

Detect Any OS

and that's all
Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

> I starting my computer and ubuntu loaded without any boot loader. So I searched in internet and the only fix I understand was with the boot repair application.

I suppose this actually meant Ubuntu did not boot?

> After installing ubuntu, using something else option and installing it on a different disk than windows 8 ,

That is not a very accurate description of what you did. First your Windows 8 is not on a GPT partitioned drive, which indicates that it couldn't be a typical UEFI installation.

Your Linux swap partition is on the Windows drive, that's not bad, but not very consistent either. The worse thing is that your root filesystem is on an **extended partition** on the second drive (sdb5). The recommended way is to put at least the root filesystem on a primary partition to have GRUB working properly. With less than 3 primary partitions on sdb, I don't even see a reason to setup an extended partition.

It looks like boot-repair did the best it could by installing GRUB to sda1 (And re-formatting it with EXT4!? Windows doesn't do that. Probably because only EXT3/4 support embedding of GRUB.), where it should have told you to reinstall with a proper partition layout. So I'll do that:

1. Please backup all data on sdb and create a primary partition to install Ubuntu there in.
2. Choose sdb as target for MBR bootloader installation for GRUB.
3. You probably need to repair your Windows bootloader (like oldfred pointed out in his comment) with `bcdboot` and reformat sda1.